# Recommend an extensible SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I have this weird situation where I have to accept email from my users. I want to be able to intercept an incoming SMTP message, see if it's authenticated (inspect the username/password myself and check those against my user database), then parse the message in full and do something (log a post in my application, for example). I need somebody to do the heavy lifting for me and take care of the SMTP protocol, transport encryption, etc and let me take care of the rest.

My problem is that I can't find an extensible SMTP server that will either let me plug into its processing pipeline or maybe embed it in my application or service. Do you know one? I'd love to program the SMTP logic in C#, but I can consider other options like external pipe programs, COM objects, running on a Unix system under Mono, etc.

Comment: Are you limited to Windows as your tags suggest?

Comment: Andrew, I'm willing to consider Linux too. Removing the Windows tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is an SMTP package included as part of the [Neokernel Web Server](http://www.neokernel.com) that may address your needs.

The API documentation is online at http://www.neokernel.com/nk_docs/index.html, look at com.neokernel.email package for details.

Comment: Thats cool, beats using a dedicated server/process for simple things